# Using an arduino or raspberry pi, how can I drive and control a proprietary diehen servomotor?

Tags: hardware

[image: motor nameplate]
I’m trying to resurrect this robot from Daihen-I need to determine how this proprietary motor and encoder are wired. Anyone got experience with this?